# R gsub alternate with pipeline - OR - alternate

Tags: r

I want to extract the following pattern using R:

When I have a string  "a|c, d", and from that I want to extract:

```
a,d 
c,d
```

Other examples:

- a|c:

  ```
  a
  c
  ```
- x|y|z, d:

  ```
  x,d
  y,d
  z,d
  ```
- a,b:

  ```
  a,b
  ```

I saw that with gsub | means an alternate character, but I can't seem to implement this to get the results I want.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that can do what you want (with a helper function to make the collapsing eaier).

```
pastelist <- function(..., sep=",", collapse=" ") 
   do.call("paste", c(as.list(...), sep=sep, collapse=collapse))

textexpand <- function(x) {
  sapply(Map(expand.grid, lapply(strsplit(x, ","), strsplit, "\\|")), pastelist)
}

textexpand("a|c,d")
# [1] "a,d c,d"
textexpand("a|c")
# [1] "a c"
textexpand("x|y|z,d")
# [1] "x,d y,d z,d"
textexpand("a,b")
# [1] "a,b"
```

Comment: Or, under the interpretation that the OP wants a table of results, stopping after expand.grid: `function(s){
  do.call(expand.grid,
    lapply(strsplit(s, ",\\s*"), function(x) strsplit(x, "\\|"))
  )
}`

Comment: @Frank thanks. your reformatting of the original question helped me to see what the real intent may have been.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 string <- c("a|c, d","x|y|z","ddwah")

 gsub(pattern = "a|b|c",replacement ="" ,x = string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read in the data and use `separate_rows` to expand it.  Finally ensure that the columns are in the desired order.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input <- c("a|c, d", "x|y|z, e", "a, b")

input %>% 
     read.csv(text = .,  header = FALSE) %>% 
     separate_rows(V1) %>% 
     select(V1, V2)
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2
1  a  d
2  c  d
3  x  e
4  y  e
5  z  e
6  a  b
```

Comment: In case I have parentheses, is there some way I can consider those? For example: a|((b|c),d) the result should be the following list: -a  -b,d  -c,d   (formatting on comments are limited, sorry)